# RStudio file pane not working and files in "~" not shown in explorer (Windows 11)

Tags: r, rstudio, windows-11

I have a really weird problem:
I have just started up my new laptop with Windows 11 (I did a reset as well to check whether any other settings had an impact) and installed R and RStudio.

When starting RStudio, I noticed that the file pane does not work correctly; I don't have the directory up button and I have files in my "~" folder which are not in the C:/users/username/Documents folder when I check in Windows Explorer (and yes hidden files are shown).

[image]

As you can see, nothing int Windows Explorer:

[image]

Also R shows this:

[image]

When I attempt to click on any of the folders, I get the following error:

[image]

These all return the correct path:

```r
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/morit/Documents"
> path.expand("~")
[1] "C:/Users/morit/Documents"
> Sys.getenv("R_USER")
[1] "C:/Users/morit/Documents"
```

I have no idea how this is happening... Any ideas?

Here is my session info:

```r
R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default


locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Austria.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_Austria.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_Austria.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                     LC_TIME=English_Austria.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Vienna
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.3.0 tools_4.3.0
```

Comment: Rstudio is an IDE, separate from R. What version of Rstudio are you using? Have you tried a daily build?

Comment: Thanks Roman, I downloaded the latest base Version 4.3.0. I also tried the latest Rstudio daily version. Do you think it might be related to the newest R version?

Comment: It looks like `C:\Users\Default` .  What do you get for `getwd()`, `path.expand("~")` and `Sys.getenv("R_USER")` ? . Having no directory up button in files pane while in working directory is expected.

Comment: Thanks margusl - I added the output of all three above. All output the expected file path.

Comment: This is not an R issue but Rstudio one. Try other versions, including newest daily build.